# Essential Grid Fancybox - Can't scroll overflow content on mobile chrome

Tags: jquery, wordpress, fancybox

Not sure it is appropriate or not to post this type of question, but just try my luck since I try to read the codes and I can't understand what I'm suppose to fix.

Basically, I develop a website using Wordpress platform and I used a premium plugin call Essential Grid to make a grid layout. Those grids will open a lightbox once clicked and Essential Grid plugin use Fancybox3 for the lightbox.

**The issue is, when in mobile, when the content is overflow, I can't scroll down to see it. The lightbox will just close and this is only happen in Chrome.** If you test it on ios Safari or Firefox, it just working good.

[Here's the staging link of the demo.](https://fancybox.nazrinnoorzan.com/)
[And here's the Fancybox JS file that they used (they got alter some of the codes).](https://fancybox.nazrinnoorzan.com/wp-content/plugins/essential-grid/public/assets/js/jquery.esgbox.min.js?ver=2.3.6)

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle with your code?

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the fact that minimum height for CSS Grid cell is auto by default. You can easily fix your issue by putting `min-height: 0;` on the content, for example:

```
.eg-lightbox-post-content {
  min-height: 0;
}
```

Comment: Already update the CSS but still same. I don't think it's because of CSS since Safari & Firefox don't have this issue.

Comment: Funny thing is that `min-height: 0;` is the right answer, but I do not have access to source code of your page, therefore I can not test where exactly it needs to be applied.